# why margin left in this example is not working?

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple example of 3 columns, here if one expands the other two will also expand.

Below is the HTML code

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
        Hello world!
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#outer {
    width:500px; 
    background:#FFCCCC;
}

#inner {
    background:#FFCC33;
    padding:10px;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:25px;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #F00;
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KCzq3/6/

Update:

see in the html if you increase the conent of one div the other two divs will show the same  height of the maximum high div, now if table-cell doesn't works, what can be the solution for this i cannot give float or inline block or it will shrink

Comment: `display:table-cell` and `margin` are incompatible.

Comment: You again... Margin will not work because it's `display:table-cell`

Comment: IDs should be unique on page

Comment: multiple elements with the same `id` is incorrect, use `class` instead of `id` for styling multiple elements

Comment: Can you guys help me with something which will give me the same UI with the margins

Comment: I'm confused...what's the question?

Comment: I have added the explanation in my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `display:table-cell` the div acts like a table and responds to table commands.

Simply put this in #outer instead, to simulate the cell-spacing effect:

```
border-spacing:25px 0;
border-collapse:separate;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KCzq3/9/

Comment: Great answer, better than mine as this also solves his second problem. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks you so much.. you rocked the post.. :) Cheers!!

Comment: Can i remove the spacing for the fisrt #inner div ?

Comment: In this case, you can add "margin-left:-25px" in #outer.

Answer (score 2):

if you use the `display:table`/`table-cell` layout, **then you should use `border-spacing` to set `margin`/space in between elements** **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KCzq3/12/)**

Comment: @powercoder23 yes it does : http://jsfiddle.net/KCzq3/12/ . just use it in the way it is suppose to be

Answer (score 0):

use `inline-block` instead of `table-cell`

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        Hello world!
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    width:500px; 
    background:#FFCCCC;
    display: table;
}

.inner {
    background:#FFCC33;
    padding:10px;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #F00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KCzq3/8/

**if you want to have divs with the same heights so:**

change the `#outer` style to this :

```
#outer {
    width:500px; 
    background:#FFCCCC;
    border-collapse: separate;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 12.5px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KCzq3/11/

Comment: But inline-block changes the UI

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: Updated the post added the explanation all the 3 divs must have same height (the maximum one's)

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
        Hello world!
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        Hello world!
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    width:500px; 
    background:#FFCCCC;
    display: table;
}

#outer:hover {
  width: 750px;
}

.inner {
    background:#FFCC33;
    padding:10px;
    width:100px;
    margin-left:25px;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #F00;
}
```

[RESULT](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/BcGAF)

**Normal State**

[image]

**On Hover**

[image]

You see, on hover, all of the inner class will expand to `width:750px` due to the `display: table` CSS property.

Comment: care to add a bit of explanation to improve your question? How does it solve the OP issue?

Comment: This will not make any difference..:P

Comment: I edited the answer to include change width when hovered using CSS

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.